# Installing GPU support for LightGBM on Google Colab

Tags: python, gpu, google-colaboratory, lightgbm

Anyone got luck trying to install GPU support for lightgbm on Google Colab using the Notebooks there?

Answer (score 6):

Very simple: just run

```
!pip install lightgbm --install-option=--gpu
```

or

```
pip install lightgbm --install-option=--gpu --install-option="--opencl-include-dir=/usr/local/cuda/include/" --install-option="--opencl-library=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libOpenCL.so"
```

Remember to enable GPU support in your notebook and add`'device':'gpu'` in the lightgbm setting. And don't forget to uninstall the version of lightgbm that don't support gpu version first.

Comment: This solution works (Sep, 2020) on Google Colab...the other one has some issues - I struggled with that for a while as it's the method suggested in the lightgbm installation docs. I would like to just highlight the fact that you have to uninstall existing lightgbm package. Colab also caches packages, so you may have to restart runtime to make sure the newly-installed lightgbm is being imported, and not the old one.

Answer (score 5):

make sure you followed the installation steps correctly

```
!git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM
%cd LightGBM
!mkdir build
%cd build
!cmake ../../LightGBM
!make -j4
```

after this you have to execute the setupfile in LightGBM folder

```
%cd LightGBM/python-package
!python3 setup.py install --gpu
```

Once thats done , you're all set.
ps: make sure you have cmake installed, if not just

```
!pip install cmake
```

Comment: you clone the first LightGbm and clone again?

Comment: i don't think you need to clone it again. my bad!

Comment: This is the one that works for me for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Most of it was following the documentation provided [here](http://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GPU-Tutorial.html), with two small tweaks to make it work on Google Colab.
Since the instances are renewed after 12 hours of usage, I post this at the beginning of my notebook to reinstall GPU support with lightgbm :

```
    !apt-get -qq install --no-install-recommends nvidia-375
    !apt-get -qq install --no-install-recommends nvidia-opencl-icd-375 nvidia-opencl-dev opencl-headers
    !apt-get -qq install --no-install-recommends git cmake build-essential libboost-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev
    !pip3 install -qq lightgbm --install-option=--gpu
```

Comment: Don't forget to "Runtime" -> "Change runtime type" -> Select "GPU" as HW Accelerator. 
To check if the GPU is there and also to see running jobs: 
!nvidia-smi

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for `lightgbm>=4.0.0` ([released in July 2023](https://pypi.org/project/lightgbm/#history))

`lightgbm` (the Python package for LightGBM), comes with GPU support already included. As long as you are on a Windows or Linux system where a wheel is available (as on Google Colab as of this writing), no additional re-installation or manual compilation is required.

In your Colab notebook, select `Edit -> Notebook Settings` and choose `T4 GPU` (or whatever other NVIDIA GPU is available).

Run the following in a notebook cell, to tell LightGBM to use the NVIDIA OpenCL installable client driver (ICD). For more details on what that is, see the OpenCL docs ([link](https://man.opencl.org/cl_khr_icd.htm;)).

```bash
!mkdir -p /etc/OpenCL/vendors && echo "libnvidia-opencl.so.1" > /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd
```

Then use `lightgbm` with GPU support by passing `"device": "gpu`, for example like this:

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=10_000)
dtrain = lgb.Dataset(X, label=y)
bst = lgb.train(
    params={
        "objective": "regression",
        "device": "gpu",
        "verbose": 1
    },
    train_set=dtrain,
    num_boost_round=5
)
```

You will see something like the following in logs, confirming that the GPU is being used for training.

```
[LightGBM] [Info] This is the GPU trainer!!
[LightGBM] [Info] Total Bins 25500
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of data points in the train set: 10000, number of used features: 100
[LightGBM] [Info] Using GPU Device: Tesla T4, Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
[LightGBM] [Info] Compiling OpenCL Kernel with 256 bins...
[LightGBM] [Info] GPU programs have been built
[LightGBM] [Info] Size of histogram bin entry: 8
[LightGBM] [Info] 100 dense feature groups (0.95 MB) transferred to GPU in 0.001878 secs. 0 sparse feature groups
[LightGBM] [Info] Start training from score 1.025020
```

NOTE: as of v4.0.0 of LightGBM, there is also a second way to use GPU acceleration for NVIDIA GPUs. Recompile `lightgbm` with CUDA support by running the following:

```bash
!pip install \
    --force-reinstall \
    --no-binary lightgbm \
    --config-settings=cmake.define.USE_CUDA=ON \
    lightgbm
```

After restarting the notebook runtime, you can use the CUDA version by passing `{"device": "cuda"}` through the parameters, like this:

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=10_000)
dtrain = lgb.Dataset(X, label=y)
bst = lgb.train(
    params={
        "objective": "regression",
        "device": "cuda",
        "verbose": 1
    },
    train_set=dtrain,
    num_boost_round=5
)
```