# Error while Trying to Utilize GPU for LightGBM Training in Google Colab: sh: 0: cannot open ./build-python.sh: No such file

Tags: google-colaboratory, lightgbm

I'm trying to utilize Google Colab's GPU for training the LightGBM model. I followed these steps:

```
! git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM
! cd LightGBM && rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake -DUSE_GPU=1 ../../LightGBM && make -j4 && cd ../python-package && sh ./build-python.sh install --precompile --gpu;
```

However, I encountered an issue with the following error message:

```
[100%] Built target lightgbm
sh: 0: cannot open ./build-python.sh: No such file
```

Answer (score 1):

The `build-python.sh` script used to compile `lightgbm` (the Python package for LightGBM) is at the root of the repo, not in the `python-package/` directory.

In addition, if you are just compiling with `-DUSE_GPU=1`, it's not necessary to compile separately. The script can do that for you.

```bash
!git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM
!cd ./LightGBM && sh ./build-python.sh install --gpu
```

These things and morre details about customizing installation are available at https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/python-package#install-from-github.

Comment: Thanks but this error will be produced:  `LightGBMError: No OpenCL device found`. Also, [here](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5914) is posted.

Comment: That sounds like a different issue from the original post here. I believe this answer should be marked as the answer for your original question. Normally I'd suggest creating a new question here on Stack Overflow for this other error you're discussing, but since you've already double-posted to LightGBM's issues page (please don't do that in the future!), let the conversation stay there.

Comment: @ebrahimi I've answered your new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77078844/3986677