# Making lightgbm work with gpu on Google colab

Tags: python, gpu, google-colaboratory, lightgbm

I am trying to work with gpus on Google colab with lightgbm. However, I am not able to make it using the gpu as the colab runtime says. I know that there are other similar questions, but none of them shows the problem I am encountering.

I have tried a lot of solutions found in many places. For example, I have tried:

```
!pip install \
     --force-reinstall \
     --no-binary lightgbm \
     --config-settings=cmake.define.USE_CUDA=ON \
     lightgbm
```

The command runs without problems but colab shows no gpu activity when training the model. I have also tried this, which is suggested in many places:

```
! git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM
! cd LightGBM && rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake -DUSE_GPU=1 ../../LightGBM && make -j4 && cd ../python-package && python3 setup.py install --precompile --gpu;
```

This command gives me this error:

> python3: can't open file '/content/LightGBM/python-package/setup.py':
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I've checked and it seems that the `/python-package` directory is not present.

---

Update:

I have changed the command, following the official guidelines (https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/python-package/README.rst). Now the commands are:

```
! git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM
! cd LightGBM && rm -r build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake -DUSE_GPU=1 -DOpenCL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libOpenCL.so -DOpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include/ ../ && make -j$(nproc)
! sudo apt install python3.10-venv
! cd /content/LightGBM && sh ./build-python.sh install --precompile
```

The commands run successfully, and i correctly see the following log when i call `lgb.train(...)`:

```
[LightGBM] [Info] This is the GPU trainer!!
```

However, this is soon followed by this exception:

```
LightGBMError: No OpenCL device found
```

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to mark this as a duplicate, but it is the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606886/installing-gpu-support-for-lightgbm-on-google-collab/77078844

Please see my answer there, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77078844/3986677, and upvote it if you find it solves the issue.

I suspect that you probably forgot to attach a GPU to your Colab instance.